# why do we need interface in this question?

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, compare

In the following code, which is from a book, assume that the **rectangle** is a class with several properties. The purpose of **ComparableRectangle** class is to compare two rectangle objects and return the area of whichever was larger, to the value of 1. Also, this class has implemented a **comparable** interface. My question is why this interface must be implemented. What happens if we write this compareTo method ourselves and do not implement this interface? Is not the purpose of the interface to use polymorphism? Here we do not want to use polymorphism, so why we implement the interface?

```
public class ComparableRectangle extends Rectangle
implements Comparable<ComparableRectangle> {

public ComparableRectangle(double width, double height) {
super(width, height);
}
    
@Override // Implement the compareTo method defined in Comparable

public int compareTo(ComparableRectangle o) {
 if (getArea() > o.getArea())
 return 1;
 else if (getArea() < o.getArea())
 return −1;
 else
 return 0;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to unless you want to have a natural ordering between like objects.  Let's say you want to sort a `List<ComparableRectangles>`.  The sort method's signature might look like this:

```
public void <T extends Comparable<? super T>> sort(List<T> list) {
}
```

If `T` does not implement the Comparable interface you will not be able to pass a list of `T` to the sort method since the method has no way of knowing how to sort the list.  The method can't just assume that it can call `compareTo` (it might not be there since it is not a method defined in the `List` interface).

fortunately, the `Collections.sort()` method allows one to sort a list of objects that don't implement the `Comparable` interface. To sort such a `List` you would have to supply a `Comparator` yourself.  Given the following class, you could do it like this:

```
class MyObject {
    int a;
    public MyObject(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return a+"";
    }
    
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}


List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.add(new MyObject((int)(Math.random()*100)));
}
System.out.println(list);
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(MyObject::getA));
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints something like this.

```
[90, 75, 10, 78, 9, 14, 79, 43, 49, 47]
[9, 10, 14, 43, 47, 49, 75, 78, 79, 90]
```

And here's a different example of multiple classes implementing a common requirement.

```
class Lion implements MealTime {
    public void feedMe() {
        System.out.println("\"How about a young gazelle\"");
    }
}

class Koala implements MealTime {
    public void feedMe() {
        System.out.println("\"I want some nice tender eucalyptus.\"");
    }
}

class Gnu implements MealTime {
    public void feedMe() {
        System.out.println("\"Just let me graze please!\"");
    }
}

interface MealTime {
    public void feedMe();
}

public class ZooManagement {
    
    public static void feedem(List<MealTime> list) {
        for (MealTime animal : list) {
            System.out.print("The " + animal.getClass().getSimpleName() + " says -  ");
            animal.feedMe();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MealTime> animals =
                List.of(new Lion(), new Koala(), new Gnu());
        feedem(animals);
    }   
}
```

Prints

```
The Lion says -  "How about a young gazelle"
The Koala says -  "I want some nice tender eucalyptus."
The Gnu says -  "Just let me graze please!"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> Lists (and arrays) of objects that implement this interface can be sorted automatically by Collections.sort (and Arrays.sort). Objects that implement this interface can be used as keys in a sorted map or as elements in a sorted set, without the need to specify a comparator.

In other words, you can implement your own compare method and it will work for you to compare two rectangles, but you won't be able to use your class in other sorted collections and classes, that expects ordering.

Comment: As the other answer explains, they don't need to implement Comparable interface for this. The OP can just pass their own comparator to sort methods. This answer is better suited as a comment imo.